# Api Platform issue with #[ApiResource]

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, attributes, api-platform.com

I've installed Api Platform v3 from scratch, followed the steps in install page (https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/) using symfony cli and it shows an empty api, no entity.
The soon I am generating an entity and marked as api entity, it throws this error

```
ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource::withDescription(): Argument #1
($description) must be of type string, null given, called in
/var/www/api_v3/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Metadata/Resource/Factory/OperationDefaultsTrait.php
on line 58
```

This goes beyond my ability to discern what it is wrong here, I am just starting with Symfony and Api Platform. It seems is related to the switch from ORM like annotations to PHP 8 attributes, but there is little to no resources on internet about this error.
Using debian 11, PHP 8.1, apache, everything up to date.

Here is the code for the Test entity

```
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\TestRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TestRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Test
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Here is the composer.json

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=8.1",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/core": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.13",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^2.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
        "phpstan/phpdoc-parser": "^1.13",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/asset": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/runtime": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "6.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "6.1.*"
    },
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/package-versions-deprecated": true,
            "symfony/flex": true,
            "symfony/runtime": true
        },
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php74": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php80": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php81": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "6.1.*"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.47"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Debian 10 buster and PHP 7.4... so I doubt it is related to the new PHP 8 attributes. After some research, this [Github thread](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3683) appeared to me as piece of answer even though I couldn't get it to work. It looks like the dependency conflict popped-up again two years later.

Comment: @gotgot1995 in my case it was the api_platform.yaml config file. Not sure which setting was wrong, but once I've empty the file it was ok.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error even after emptying the api_platform.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource` instead of the annotation `ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource`. Does that help ?